# Credit card payments in PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, credit-card

I am looking at https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle but I was hoping someone could explain at a higher level what is required.

For example, what are things I need to do before even worrying about the coding side of it. Do I need `https`, do I need to sign up with some credit card company/service first, if so who is trusted, etc?

I am hoping for a crash course in the basics before I start coding any solution.

Thanks

Comment: PCI Compliance is something you should be looking into if you're going to be processing payments/storing CC details on your end.

Comment: https://stripe.com/

Comment: I would recommend looking into [Stripe](http://www.stripe.com) and using them instead of trying to roll your own, accepting and storing CC details is a huge security problem if you're not sure what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate to your application an API such as Conekta, PayPal, Stripe, etc.. The SSL is not always mandatory but always very recommendable!

Comment: Are there any trusted third party services which handle credit card payments off-site besides Paypal? So I don't have to do SSL on my site, and I could just redirect the user elsewhere for example - and there's some callback to my site once the purchase is confirmed?

Comment: Not that I know, may be Recurly might work for you. And as I said, SSL is not mandatory for Conekta or Stripe, but your clients would feel much better putting their credit card information in a site with SSL. The callback is called "web hook" and yeah, all of the options I mentioned have a web hook available.